# Sudarshana Homam and its benefits

Tags: vedas, mantras, homam

It is learnt that there are ten types of Mantravada  doshas{ill effects of black magic } from ten directions, called Marana, Uchatana, Mohana, Vidhveshana, Manthra, Tanthra, Vishachoorna, Prayoga, Abhichara and Kruthrima.

Sudarshana Homam is considered an ideal remedy for this.

What is Sudarshana Homam?

What are the various benefits of Sudarshana Homam?

Comment: Uday there is one more point to it Sudarshan homa is like the ultimate solution to every problem a grihasta encounters so its not just physical wellbeing and all Tantric aspects but total wealth including spiritual (Laxmi) since its an incarnation of Shriman Narayana it automatically brings Devi Laxmi with it which in turn ensures well-being(material as well as spiritual) of the Bhagwata/Vaishnava.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sudarshana Homa
>   Relief from unexplainable diseases and illnesses.
>   In two instances this homam is performed--
>   1.To take charge of your enemies and to relieve you from unexplainable sufferings and worries. 
>   2. To drive away evil spirits which was kept on individual or his family.
>
> This effective Homa helps you to take charge of your enemies and to relieve you from unexplainable sufferings and worries. Get yourself empowered with positive energy or vibration by performing this Homa. It also helps to foreseen dangers and perils in the pathway of success.
>
> Lord Sudarshana is the chief deity of this powerful Homa who uses his mighty weapon "Chakra" to grant immediate relief to the sufferings of his devotees. Also, the sins are rooted out by the intensity of His disc.
>
> The "Sudarshana Chakra" contains healing characteristics. Therefore performing Sudarshana Homa relieves you from afflictions of fever and unknown health sufferings. This is the appropriate Homa which is conducted to vanquish your enemies and protects you from harmful things, fear of ire things, negative chants, evil eye etc.
>
> A legend has it that once Sudarshana Ashtakam chanting had saved the people of a village who were struck by plague epidemic.
>
> It is a Pancharatra Agama ritual.
>
> Recommended time
>   Ekadashi, Dwadasi and Pournami Tithis that fall on Wednesdays and Saturdays, during the Budha Horas are considered favorable to perform Sudarshana Homa
>   **Source---www.priestservices.com/our-services/sudarshana-homa**

Comment: You forgot to write about origin of Sudarshan homa i.e it is a pancharatra ritual, please add this to your answer.

Comment: @yogi--thanks will add int he answer.

Comment: @uday--Although your question is academic I have to provide the info to enable you to grasp line by line and store in your memory.  Kindly share ur mail id so that you can view the existence of Lord sudarsana.

Comment: @UdayKrishna--If anybody is willing to do sudarsana homa please let me know. We will do that. It will take minimum 6 hours. Ganapathy, Navagraha and Sudarsana homa to be done as per homa sastras for performing sudarsana homam. We will give Lord sudarsana laminated photo to the doer.

Comment: I want to see the images that you want to share, is it fine if I send you an email which you have on your profile and you reply with those images?

Comment: @chinmay--Sure  pl go  ahead.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Can you email me photos. My email id is in my profile page.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan I have sent you an email.

Comment: @Chinmay--I have forwarded 2 mails    one ganapathi homam and other sudasana homam  with images.

Comment: @the destroyer--will do that.

Comment: @Parthasarathy Hi.. I'll also mail you.. please send me also...

Comment: @tezz-Sure  will share the images

Comment: @UdayKrishna--Done.

Answer (score 5):

A Homa is a fire sacrifice. Sudarshana Homa is sacrifice to Sudarshana Chakra ,the weapon of Lord Vishnu.

**What is Sudarshana Homa and how to do it?**

> ! Perform Viśvaksena Pūjā and other preliminaries. ! Invoke Sudarśana
>   in the Kumbha as for Puṇyāha Vācanam and offer 16 upacāras. ! Perform
>   all the rites of agni mukhaṁ up to āghāram and ājyabhāgam as per
>   Vadika vidhi or Pañcarātrika Nitya Homa vidhi and **then perform
>   pradhāna homa with the following mantras adding svāhā to the end. One
>   may use all the mantras according to time and place, or one may just
>   use the mūla mantra and māla mantra.** Homa may also be performed with
>   the Sudarśana Kavacam - adding svāhā to the end of each verse

There are 9 mantras in all.I'm not giving all of them but only the Mula , Mala & Gayatri mantras with the warning **that one should not learn rituals from internet**:

> **1. mūla mantra** oṁ sahasrāra huṁ phaṭ svāhā ||
>   **2. māla mantra** oṁ kliṁ kṛṣṇāya govindāya gopijanavallabhāya parāya parama puruṣāya paramātmane, para-karma mantra yantra tantra
>   auṣadhayaḥ astra śastrāṇi saṁhara saṁhara, mṛtyor mokṣaya mokṣaya, oṁ
>   namo bhagavate mahā-sudarśanāya dīptre jvāla parītāya, sarva-dik
>   kṣobhaṇa-karāya huṁ phaṭ brahmaṇe parama jyotiṣe svāhā ||
>   **3. gāyatri** 1 oṁ sudarśanāya vidmahe | hetirājāya dhīmahi | tannas cakra pracodayāt ||

**The following screenshot and all informations given above are taken from a Panchratra Prayoga book.**

[image]

Few benefits of doing the Homa-

> Protects us from enemies and evil spells. Remedy (Parihara) for 
>   breaking the evil spells. Removes obstacles and makes your mission
>   successful. Remedy from 10 different types of Mantravada  doshas from
>   10 directions called Marana, Uchatana, Mohana, Vidhveshana, Manthra,
>   Tanthra, Visha choorna, Prayoga, Abhichara and Kruthrima. Helps to
>   improve our business. Removes your worries and grants happiness.
>   Protects our property.  Improves our energy level. Grants the
>   performer health, wealth and prosperity   Protects home and family
>   from evil forces like Bhoota, Preta, Pishacha, Dakinee, Shakinee,
>   Mohinee Brahmarakshasa, Betala. Eliminate undesirable elements. 
>   Relief from unexplainable diseases and illnesses    Rremedy (Parihara)
>   for “Drishti doshas”